# How do I stop my vBulletin forum from having unregistered guests spamming it?

Tags: spam, vbulletin

It seems my vbulletin forum is still having problems with unregistered guests spamming threads and members Inbox on the forum.  Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I currently use stopforumspam's plugin:

http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=176481

Give it a try.